# Networking doesn't start after upgrade with new upstart system

Tags: networking, server, upgrade, upstart

I have upgraded to the stable version of ubuntu server and my network doesn't start. There should be some problem with the new upstart service, because the network seems to try to load a dhcp, but i have configured a static ip in the networking configuration files.

I try to run `/etc/init.d/networking start`, but the response is that this is not the correct command. So I try `service networking start` and the answer is that the job doesn't exists.

However, I can see the networking file in the `init.d` and in the `init` folders. I try `service networking status` and the process response is that the service is stopped.

I have rebooted the server and the problem persists.

I only get the network working manually with the `ifconfig` command line

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `service network-manager start`?

Comment: network-manager is not installed. I have no GUI installed on it, just control by console

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The problem was the mixing that some process make between the /var/run and /var/lock folders with the new /run and /run/lock folders.

I found the solution in this link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859432. I just had to make the symlinks and the network started ok after rebooting:

```
sudo ln -s /run /var/run
sudo ln -s /run/lock /var/lock
```